# In a `SqlCommand`, what timespan does the `CommandTimeout` actually represent?

Tags: sql, .net, timeout, sqldatareader, sqlcommand

I am querying a Microsoft SQL Database using the `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` and `SqlReader`, much like described in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-data-using-a-datareader

Now, an `SqlCommand` allows to set the `CommandTimeout`, and I am doing it like so (simplified):

```
using (SqlConnection connection = GetConnection()) {
    connection.Open();
    using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand()) {

        command.CommandText = query; //My custom SQL query
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        //Set Timeout
        command.CommandTimeout = timeout.Value; //My custom timeout

        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader()) {
            while (reader.Read()) {
                //Read row by row and do stuff
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**My question is, to what does the Timeout actually apply to?** Is it

- The time spent in `ExecuteReader()`
- The time spent in `Read()`
- both of those
- something else?

There seems no documentation of this specifically, neither in MSDN nor on the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will apply to the time executing the command against the database which is `command.ExecuteReader()` which is complete by the time you start reading the records. You could test that by putting a break point in after that on the `while` and and sitting there - you won't hit your timeout.